# Questionnaire from database saving response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 4 model classes here and I have pulled the questionnaire fields, questions, and answeroptions in the html-form and I have a controller action method where I want to post this questionnaire data and save the response and questionnaire details. Can anyone please help me in this?

```
public class Question
{
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public List<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
}

   public class AnswerOption
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }

}
   public class Response
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long QuestionnaireId { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public long AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public AnswerOption AnswerOption { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
public class Questionnaire
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string DBA { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddress { get; set; }
    public string MailingCity { get; set; }
    public string MailingState { get; set; }
    public string MailingZip { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Html,

```
@{ var questions = GetAllQuestions();
}
<form name="updateForm" asp-controller="Questionnaire" asp-action="SubmitApplication" id="updateForm" asp-return-route="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="panel panel-midnightblue">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2>Questionnaire Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <div class="row horizontal-nav">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-stack-1x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <strong>Please enter your information here.</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <span class="grid__col-4">
            <label class="text-large mb0 alignleft">Business Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="BusinessName" />
        </span>
        <span class="grid__col-3">
            <label class="text-large mb0">Email Address</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Email" />
        </span>
        <span class="grid__col-3">
            <label class="text-large mb0">DBA</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="DBA" />
        </span>
        <span class="grid__col-4">
            <label class="text-large mb0 alignleft">Mailing Address</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="MailingAddress" />
        </span>
        <span class="grid__col-3">
            <label class="text-large mb0">City</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="MailingCity" />
        </span>

        <span class="grid__col-2">
            <label class="text-large mb0">State</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="MailingState" />
        </span>

        <span class="grid__col-2">
            <label class="text-large mb0">Zip</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="MailingZip" />
        </span>

        <span>
            <input class="form-control hidden" name="CreatedOn" value="@DateTime.Now"/>
        </span>
        <div class="grid__col-2">
            <label class="text-large mb0">Signature</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Signature"/>
        </div>
        <span class="grid__col-2">
            <label class="text-large mb0">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Title" />
        </span>
        @for (var i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++)
        {
            <span class="grid__col-2">
                <label class="text-large mb0">@questions[i].Text</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="Responses[@i].QuestionId" value="@questions[i].Id"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="Responses[@i].Id" value="@i"/>
                @foreach (var answerOption in questions[i].AnswerOptions)
                {
                    if (answerOption.Option != null)
                    {
                        <span>
                            <input type="radio" value="@answerOption.Option" name="@answerOption.QuestionId"/>
                            <label>@answerOption.Option</label>
                        </span>

                    }
                    else if (answerOption.Option == null)
                    {
                        <span>

                            <input type="text" id="@answerOption.QuestionId" value=""/>
                        </span>
                    }
                }

            </span>
        }

    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="form-group center">
            <button id="submitInfo" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit Application</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller action method

```
    public IActionResult SubmitApplication(Questionnaire questionnaire)
    {
        var successSaveQuestionnaire = Base.RepoService.SaveQuestionnaire(questionnaire);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", successSaveQuestionnaire ? new { Message = FeedbackMessageEnum.SaveQuestionnaireSuccessEnum } : new { Message = FeedbackMessageEnum.SaveQuestionnaireFailedEnum });
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: you forgot to ask the question

Comment: @Cal279 It's posting the filled Questionnaire values to the controller but not Response values.
I want it post all the filled responses to save in db

Comment: Use EditorTemplate as described in this post [Getting a list of radio button values in ASP MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844763/getting-a-list-of-radio-button-values-in-asp-mvc-3/12845534#12845534)

Comment: pass questionnaire model to view and create other fields based on the model.

Comment: @Shyju thank you for the link, mine is in asp.net core and I dont know if I can use Editor template in Core.

Comment: Yes you can. It is same for asp net core. Just follow the post